# Retrieve MySQL data from XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

The situation is, I formatted my drive C, where as the XAMPP was installed in Drive D. I reinstalled the XAMPP in new folder, copied htdocs from old installation folder. So the web is there but not the MySQL db.

I tried copying the entire mysql folder to the new installation directory but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you not backup your database? Do you recall running `mysqldump` command?

Comment: no i forgot that.. but well restarting the mysql service and copying ibdata1 resolved the issue :)